# positioning divs within a div

Tags: html, css

[image]

So I'm trying to recreate the mockup on this PDF with HTML5/CSS3. But I'm having the hardest time trying to position those images this way. Whenever I use a float: left on them they pop out of the main container (the white one). Does anyone have any recommendations? Thank you!
--Arielle

Comment: Use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for positioning. They have a whole grid-system. See [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: This is for a website that's already made. I'm building a static page here.

Comment: Ik zou een tabel gebruiken denk ik...?

Comment: It looks like a 'html table' to me ;-/ or use the 'css table'  stuff. rather useful. see [Complete Guide to the Table Element](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/). With that and 'BEM', css almost becomes 'fun'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arielle,

I've worked with a similar layout before, and didn't end up using floats.

What ended up working the best for me is to absolutely position the image elements, and set a slightly higher z-index so the border and image lays nicely on top of the text, but stays beautifully responsive. Recommend using percentages if possible, makes for much smoother media queries.

Do you happen to have a link to view so I can give a more specific suggestion?

Agree with the above response for Bootstap - a great system to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you forget about using floats, and instead use something like this:

```
#div{display:inline-block;}
```

In your html, align your code like this:

```
   <div id="#div"></div><!--
--><div id="#div"></div><!--
--><div id="#div"></div>
```

or like this:

```
<div id="#div"></div><div id="#div"></div><div id="#div"></div>
```

If you add padding or a border, add this to your #div css:

```
#div{display:inline-block;padding:1em;border:1px solid #000;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Seriously, take a look:

**http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/wf4tLh3z/**

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap would help you a lot -- and it would be mobile-responsive.

Short of that, you could also try:
`display: table-cell`